# Best way to organize project to keep update from original repo

Tags: git, version-control, project

I have a project  started from a commercial source, I add my features and want keep update from original code.

My needs:

- hold commercial source project (named `AA`) in a git repository (named `BB`) from source code archive
- starting a new repository (named `CC`) based on `BB` and add my fonctionalities (using gitflow or GitHub flow)
- update `BB` from source code archive when it is updated by commercial owner
- commit theses changes to `CC`
- this projet includes 3 applications:

  - api
  - admin
  - frontend
- folder structure is organized like this:

```
root project
├── api
│   ├── src
│   ├── ...
├── admin
│   ├── src
│   ├── ...
├── frontend
│   ├── src
│   ├── ...
```

Do I split my project into a master repository and three sub repository or keep one repository ??

What is the best way to do to achieve my needs (forking, branches,  submodules, git-vendor, gitflow or GitHub flow, ...) ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Single repository will be easier in my experience. I would keep a branch `upstream` (`BB`) where you bring in changes from the source archive, and a branch `main` (`CC`) for your own development.

If you split the project into three repos, one for each app, then you manually have to update three repos every time `AA` is updated. So I wouldn't do that unless you are forced to (needing different permissions for each app, publishing them separately, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I will follow your method.